# List of Enums Spring Rest API

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, enums

I am making a rest API and trying to create a property of an Embeddable Entity that is a List of enums.

## Schedule.java

```
@Embeddable
public class Schedule {
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @ElementCollection(targetClass = DayOfWeekEnum.class)
    private List<DayOfWeekEnum> daysOfWeek;

    public enum DayOfWeekEnum {
        SUNDAY,
        MONDAY,
        TUESDAY,
        WEDNESDAY,
        THURSDAY,
        FRIDAY,
        SATURDAY
    }

    //getters, setters, and constructors
}
```

## Task.java

```
@Entity
public class Task extends BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private final Long id;

    @NotNull(message = "Task description can not be null.")
    @NotBlank(message = "Task description can not be nothing.")
    private String description;

    @NotNull(message = "Task must either be completed or not.")
    private boolean complete;

    @Embedded
    private Schedule schedule;

    //getters, setters, and constructors
}
```

I have created a Task Entity containing a Schedule object with `daysOfWeek` filled with `DayOfWeekEnum.SUNDAY` but in the rest API display, the property is empty.

```
"daysOfWeek": []
```

Why is it not displaying the following?

```
"daysOfWeek": ["SUNDAY"]
```

Comment: It should work, just tested it on my side. Can we have the code of the entity containing the Schedule?

Comment: I have updated my code. The Entity containing Schedule is Task.

Comment: Hmm no, I still cannot reproduce the error. Maybe also the code where you create your `Task` entity with `DayOfWeekEnum.SUNDAY`?

Comment: The issue was with the way I was saving the object. Many Tasks were mapped to the same Schedule object, which caused the Rest API to display an empty Enum array.

Comment: I see, thanks for the info. I would also thought that it would work with the same `Schedule` object but I didn't test it.